# How to read attribute of a parent node from a child node in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath

Just want to know how to read an attribute of a parent node(A) from a child node(c) in XSLT. code:

```
<A attr1="xx">
  <b>
    <c>
    </c>
  </b>
</A>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="c">
  <xsl:value-of select="attribute of A node">
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A` is not actually the parent of `c` but an ancestor (`b` is the parent!), but the code you are looking for is this

```
<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::A/@attr1">
```

(You could replace `ancestor` with `parent` in the case `A` was the direct parent of `c`)

You could also do this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../@attr1">
```

But this would assume `A` is always the 'grand-parent` (i.e. the parent of the parent).